# How can I process this big data in scala IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

It has been a few days and i started learning Scala on IntelliJ and I am learning all by myself. Please bear my rookie mistakes. I have a csv file with more than 10,000 rows and 13 columns.

The heading of of the columns are:

**Category | Rating | Reviews | Size | Installs | Type | Price | Content Rating | Genres | Last updated | Current Version | Android Version**

I did manage to read and display the the csv file with the following code:

```
import scala.io.Source


object task {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for(line <- Source.fromFile("D:/data.csv"))
    {
      println(line)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that this code **displays one alphabet or digit, moves onto the next line and displays the next alphabet or digit. It does not display a row in one line.**

I want to find out the best app for each category (ART_AND_DESIGN, AUTO_AND_VEHICLES, BEAUTY…,) based on its assigned priorities of reviews and ratings. The priorities are defined as 60 % for “reviews” and 40% for “rating” columns respectively. Calculate a value for each category (ART_AND_DESIGN, AUTO_AND_VEHICLES, BEAUTY…,) by using these assigned values of priorities. This value will help us out to find the best app in each category. You can use Priority formula equation as follows.

Priority = ( (((rating/max_rating) * 100) * 0.4) + (((reviews/max_reviews) * 100) * 0.6) )

Here max_rating is maximum rating of given data in same category like category(“ART_AND_DESIGN”) maximum rating is “4.7”, max_reviews is maximum reviews of app in same category like category(“ART_AND_DESIGN”) maximum reviews is “295221”. So priority value will be for first data record of category(“ART_AND_DESIGN”) is:

Rating= 4.1, reviews= 159,

max_rating= 4.7, max_reviews= 295221

My question is, how can i store every column in an array? That is how i plan on computing the data. If there is any other way to solve the above problem, i am open to suggestions.

I can upload a small chunk of the data if anyone wants to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Source` gives you a byte `Iterator` by default. To iterate through lines, use `.getLines`:

```
 Source.fromFile(fileName)
   .getLines
   .foreach(println)
```

To split lines into arrays, use `split` (assuming the column values do not include separator):

```
  val arrays = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.map(_.split("|"))
```

It is better to avoid using raw arrays though. Creating a case class makes for much better, readable code:

```
   case class AppData(
     category: String,
     rating: Int,
     reviews: Int, 
     size: Int,
     installs: Int, 
     `type`: String, 
     price: Double,
     contentRating: Int, 
     generes: Seq[String], 
     lastUpdated: Long,
     version: String,
     androidVersion: String
  ) {
     def priority(maxRating: Int, maxReview: Int) = 
       if(maxRatings == 0 || maxReviews == 0) 0 else 
         (rating * 0.4 / maxRating + reviews * 0.6 /maxReview) * 100
  }

  object AppData {
    def apply(str: String) = {
       val fields = str.split("|")
       assert(fields.length == 12)
       AppData(
         fields(0),
         fields(1).toInt,   
         fields(2).toInt,
         fields(3).toInt,
         fields(4).toInt,
         fields(5),
         fields(6).toDouble,
         fields(7).toInt,
         fields(8).split(",").toSeq,
         fields(9).toLong,
         fields(10),
         fields(11)
       )
    }
  }
```

Now you can do what you want pretty neatly:

```
  // Read the data, parse it and group by category
  // This gives you a map of categories to a seq of apps 
  val byCategory = Source.fromFile(fileName)
    .map(AppData)
    .groupBy(_.category)

  // Now, find out max ratings and reviews for each category
  // This could be done even nicer with another case class and 
  // a monoid, but tuple/fold will do too 
  // It is tempting to use `.mapValues` here, but that's not a good idea
  // because .mapValues is LAZY, it will recompute the max every time 
  // the value is accessed!
  val maxes = byVategory.map { case (cat, data) => 
     cat -> 
        data.foldLeft(0 -> 0) { case ((maxRatings, maxReviews), in) => 
          (maxRatings max in.rating, maxReviews max in.reviews)
        }
  }.withDefault( _ => (0,0))

  // And finally go through your categories, and find best for each, 
  // that's it!
  val bestByCategory = byCategory.map { case(cat, apps) => 
    cat -> apps.maxBy { _.priority.tupled(maxes(cat)) }
  }
```

Comment: thank you. This helped a lot. I'm sorry i cannot upvote your answer because I am a new user